# Firefox Print CSS Overflow Issue

Tags: css, printing

I'm working on setting up a report on a webpage to be print friendly. It prints "ok" in Chrome and Safari but with Firefox I'm having an issue where it only prints the first 1.5 charts and then just skips to the footer. I've seen in other places where adding "overflow:visible;" fixed this issue. I've added to any wrapping element and still getting nowhere. Any ideas?

The report can be found here http://vitaferm.com/hay-report/

CSS I'm trying at the moment is

```
@media print {
    /* print styles go here */
    *{
        overflow:visible;
    }
    .d-print-none {
        display:none;
    }
    canvas {
        display: block;
        clear:both;
        width:100%;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .print-block {
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        max-width: 100%;
        flex: 100%;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .chartjs-hidden-iframe {
        overflow:visible;
    }
    .row {
        overflow:visible;
    }
}
```